# what is the use of the keyMirror node package part of facebook's library?

Tags: node.js, facebook, reactjs

This is the keyMirror package found here 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/keymirror

it defines it as A simple utility for creating an object with values equal to its keys

```
Input: {key1: val1, key2: val2}
Output: {key1: key1, key2: key2}
```

But why would i need to do this?

how is this different from say,

```
{OPTION_ONE:1, OPTION_TWO:2, OPTION_THREE:3}
```

Why would an application find the below transformation to the above input useful?

```
{OPTION_ONE:OPTION_ONE, OPTION_TWO:OPTION_TWO, OPTION_THREE:OPTION_THREE}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's making an Enum object (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type)

You could do, like you said `{OPTION_ONE:1, OPTION_TWO:2, OPTION_THREE:3}`, which is a similar Enum object, but what if you wanted to know if the value `6` was a value from the enum? You would have to loop over all the keys and check all the values.

But, if the keys and values match, then you can just check if the key exists in the object to know if the value also does.

```
var mirror = keyMirror({a: null, b:null});
var someValue = 'd';
var validValue = mirror[someValue] !== undefined;
```

Comment: `{OPTION_ONE:OPTION_ONE}` you're saying keyMirror assigns something which is "defined" to the value part of this key-value pair? since OPTION_ONE(value) is otherwise an undefined variable?

Comment: `keyMirror({a: null, b:null})` returns `{a: 'a', b: 'b'}`