# What are the benefits of React's keyMirror?

Tags: javascript, facebook, enums, reactjs

I have worked through a number of React tutorials recently, specifically those employing the Flux architecture. All of these tutorials have utilised `react/lib/keymirror` in various forms.

I understand **what** it does, but I am not convinced I fully understand the benefits it provides. However, that may suggest my understanding of *what* it does isn't quite correct!

My understanding is:

1. It produces an [enumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900983/what-is-the-use-of-the-keymirror-node-package-part-of-facebooks-library).
2. Enumerables are typically used in functional languages, but are also useful in [object-orientated code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/211811/in-what-situations-does-it-make-sense-to-use-an-enumeration-when-writing-object).
3. There are benefits to [minification](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/reactjs/dzVhoavALwI/eeezh-kKsr0J) although, I'm not sure I fully understand these in this case.
4. [Bill Fisher](https://www.linkedin.com/in/fisherwebdev) states that it would not be unreasonable to use Strings in place of the constants, and that really the benefit comes when you have a large number of constants.

I suppose the question is, in small-medium scale applications, does defining constants once within the keyMirror and then requiring and referencing them in two different locations (actions and stores) provide any tangible benefit compared to Strings, referenced only in actions and stores?

If, as Bill says, it helps to see a list of the constants in one place, it would still be less code to just keep a txt file with the string constants listed there.

Answer (score 13):

You'll have to wait for someone from the React team to confirm this, but I'm guessing one reason is because constant string literals in business logic are not encouraged by their style guide. In situations with a lot of developers working on the same code, if logic is built by setting and checking hard-coded strings, it is less obvious where to go to find the origin of any term.

The second reason is related, but certain IDEs will let you automatically find, complete, or refactor property names, but not literal strings. Having the string defined in one place makes those workflows much easier.

Finally, better optimization is possible since all the enumerable references can be processed by UglifyJS, which can rename the symbol to be shorter without affecting either the legibility of dev code or the robustness of any references.

So I would say for anything but small short-term applications, moving literal strings into well-organized constant objects is a good idea. KeyMirror is just one kind of helper for this that guarantees the property values will match the keys. I believe this is so that you can re-use the value of any property as a valid key.

Comment: Thanks. Some good thoughts there. Things I hadn't considered.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm fairly sure uglify only renames things like locally scoped variable names...not object properties. If uglify started renaming object properties then anywhere anyone ever used `myObj['property']` would instantly be broken...i.e. half the web.

Comment: @JimboJonny Yeah that's probably true. I swear I've heard of a tool (Closure Compiler?) parsing and introspecting the code to check if it can shorten properties, but I'm not sure. And at that point you'd think the compiler could also find and replace redundant string literals.

Comment: I can confirm, Webstorm finds his way up to the key when ctrl + click - which seems to be high value, when you expect some code located in one file to work based on variables defined in another one..

Comment: Thoughtful answer. Much appreciated.